# I can't run truffle commands in powershell Ise

Tags: truffle, truffle-compile

I am looking around for questions similar to mine but basically I cannot run any truffle commands in the powershell Ise ONLY. I can make it run on the node.js command line.

example:

```
> PS C:\Users\user\Documents\internship\Blockcerts\proof-of-existence-master>
> truffle compile truffle : The term 'truffle' is not recognized as the
> name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
> the  spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
> path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
> + truffle compile
> + ~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (truffle:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I tried to follow up a similar question where the answer was to uninstall and install the following but this still occurs.

Comment: Can you try `truffle.cmd` instead ?

Comment: @Ismael hmm I deleted most truffle files from that folder already so i don't think that will work

Comment: I was just asking it is a know issue that truffle.cmd should be used on windows from the command line, but I don't know if this also applies to a power shell console. I'll check when I've the chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Try it
If it was working alright previously, uninstalling and reinstalling truffle should work. `npm uninstall -g truffle` `npm install -g truffle`

-g truffle install then work the issue.

In case this does not work, below will work.

```
run npm init #then will make a new npm project particularly package.json
run npm i truffle #then will download node modules 
run ./node_modules/.bin/truffle init #then will create a truffle project
```

Try it

Thank You!

Comment: strange, in a way it works however I have to use the  ./node_modules/.bin/ to do the commands on powershell

Comment: I did the same but got the following error. Error: Something already exists at the destination. `truffle init` and `truffle unbox` must be executed in an empty folder. Stopping to prevent overwriting data.

Answer (score 0):

set the path in the environment variable:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

1.Create a director coin and a sub-directory authcoin

2.cd to coin

```
run npm init #then will make a new npm project particularly package.json
run npm i truffle #then will download node modules 
run cd authcoin/
run ./../node_modules/.bin/truffle init #then will create a truffle project
```

or if you run last command in coin directory the error might occur.

```
Error: Something already exists at the destination. `truffle init` and     `truffle unbox` must be executed in an empty folder. Stopping to prevent overwriting data.
```