# Running Npm init on powershell but its stuck and I can't proceed

Tags: truffle, json-rpc, nodejs

I can't run truffle commands on windows powershell so I went to do the steps
[that I got here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/37296/i-cant-run-truffle-commands-in-powershell-ise/37300#37300).
However npm init got me stuck and I can't proceed:

Here is the stuck screen:

[image: current screen]

EDIT: After I uninstalled and reinstalled truffle

[image]

Comment: if you have installed npm globally, it shall work with normal command prompt too. If not, try running the cmd/Powershell as administrator and then try.

Comment: Î tried it but its still stuck and when I stop it, it says its stopping but does not go back to the proper interface @Rajesh

Comment: Try to un-install and re-install again

Comment: @Rajesh it still won't work, not even truffle init

Comment: @Rajesh PS C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming> npm uninstall npm -g
npm : npm ERR! npm uninstall [<@scope>/]<pkg>[@<version>]... [--save-prod|--save-dev|--save-optional] [--no-save]
At line:1 char:1
+ npm uninstall npm -g
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (npm ERR! npm un...al] [--no-save]:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError    is what I get