# During truffle init - got error "something already exisits at the destination"

Tags: truffle

> Error: Something already exists at the destination. Please unbox in an
>   empty fol der. Stopping to prevent overwriting data.
>       at C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~
>   \truffle-box\lib\utils\unbox.js:22:1

Comment: I have the same issue but in OSX. So it is independent from OS type

Comment: I have answered here. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/54951/43838

Answer (score 2):

To perform `truffle init` the folder should be completely empty.

Remember that could be some hidden files, you can check them from the console with the command `ls -a`.

If so, you need or to delete them or you can easily start creating a new folder from scratch.