# "truffle init" problem

Tags: truffle, tokens

What to do to resolve below issue coming in initiating a truffle project?

```
YuweideMacBook-Air:vantoken yuwei$ truffle version
Truffle v4.1.4 (core: 4.1.4)
Solidity v0.4.21 (solc-js) 

YuweideMacBook-Air:vantoken yuwei$ **truffle init**
Downloading...
Error: Something already exists at the destination. Please unbox in an empty folder. Stopping to prevent overwriting data.
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/truffle-box/lib/utils/unbox.js:22:1
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Comment: Do it on a empty folder.

Comment: i did it before,  but it doesn't work, actually vantoken is the new folder

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working on Truffle v4, try these commands in an empty folder:

```
npm init -y  
truffle init
```

You can use `truffle init --force` as well. Check out this [Truffle docs](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/creating-a-project) for this.

You might want to upgrade Truffle to v5 since v5 allows you to run `truffle init` in a non-empty folder as well.

Comment: YuweideMacBook-Air:demo1 yuwei$ npm init -y
Wrote to /Users/yuwei/Desktop/1110/demo1/package.json:

{
  "name": "demo1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "truffle-config.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}

 and it doesnt work

Comment: YuweideMacBook-Air:demo1 yuwei$ truffle init
Downloading...
Error: Something already exists at the destination. Please unbox in an empty folder. Stopping to prevent overwriting data.
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/truffle-box/lib/utils/unbox.js:22:1
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
YuweideMacBook-Air:demo1 yuwei$

Comment: Did you tried other methods as well? Apart from this, if you want, you can change the Truffle source code as well. Check [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/49037/53398) answer to see how.

Comment: i have deleted the truffle and reinstall it again. then it works ,,,, thanks all