# can not install truffle?

Tags: truffle

truffle does not work after insall using (npm install -g truffle) command . this message appears "removed 5 packages, changed 1105 packages, and audited 1074 packages in 28m

81 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

47 vulnerabilities (24 low, 18 moderate, 5 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
npm audit fix

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details."

and when using any command with truffle this appears
"truffle : The term 'truffle' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
is correct and try again.

Comment: Does this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/37300 work for you?

Comment: @Ismael no solution of them work

Comment: It might be that node isn't installed properly or there's something wrong in the PATH environment. I'd suggest to try using a tool like nvm or similar to manage node installation for you user.

Comment: finally, it worked by using this command before installation : Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted